# ASPX page displaying multiple RDLC files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rdlc

I have a requirement where 30+ RDLC reports are to be displayed in the project. So I did manage to generate the ASPX page to display one RDLC file data.

As there are 30+ reports to be added, it will be a very bad approach to create 30+ ASPX files, for each RDLC files. Do we have an alternative to render certain RDLC based on any parameter type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps are simple. Follow the instructions given in http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-create-RDLC-report-step-by-step-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx.

1. Create a aspx page for the generic report viewing.
2. Don't maap any RDLC files with the aspx page (these are to be done manually in the codebehind).
3. In the code behind, you can configure the RDLC paths/RDLC datasource and every parameter that the RDLC needs.

Comment: This was a good solution from architecture point of view. Designed one aspx page named ReportViewer.aspx and from the code behind you can set the rdlc path.